# Changing query in Spring Security.xml file, using only one table instead of two

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-security

In the `jdbc-user-service`, which provided by Spring security, I have seen demo project do things like this:

```
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Now, this works when two tables `users` and `user_roles` are created in the database.

Now what I am trying to do is to instead of creating two separate tables, I only want to create one table that contains all these attributes. And for login I do not want to `username` instead of using `user_email`. Is it possible? How do I make changes to the `<jdbc-user-service/>`? I have tried several ways but got errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The restrictions imposed on you while editing these two queries are not too strong. You just need to respect the:

- return values (values you select): username + password + enabled ; username + role
- input parameters: username

Apart from these, you should be able to modify the query and use any kind of table structure to represent your user structure.

**Note:**
The reason for not having only one but two in the default implementation is to allow many-to-many connections to be created for users and roles. This in practice means that you can assign multiple roles (eg. "reviewer", "editor", "admin") to the same user. This might not be neccessary for a very simple application, but it can become a must-have feature very soon.